# Add pandas DataFrame to SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I want to add data from a Pandas DataFrame to SQL.
I have tried to use `.tosql()` but if I use `if_exists='append', index = True` it will add even if a row with same index already exists.

Does anyone know how to add the data if the index is not already there and replace the existing data if there is already a same index.

Here is my code:

```
mydb = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
data = # the dataframe
data.to_sql(table_name, mydb, if_exists='append', index = True)
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

here is the sample data I'm trying to add: https://jpst.it/2nFvu

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can we try the below code:

```
    data.to_sql(table_name, mydb, if_exists='replace', index = False)
```

Comment: I need the index as it the row title. So, I can't set it to False

Comment: Have you tried setting it to True instead?

Comment: Yes, but it is adding the duplicates instead of replacing the existing values.